# String Matching query in BIGQUERY times out

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a select statement:

```
select
    M.FA_Unique_Listing_Identifier_Ref_ID
    ,P.ATTOM_ID
    ,P.ParcelNumberRaw Parcel
    ,M.Assessors_Parcel_Identification_Number
    ,M.Listing_Tracking_ID
    ,P.CensusTract GEOID
    ,M.Current_Original_Listing_Date
    ,M.Add_Change_Delete_Indicator
    ,M.FA_Calculated_Days_on_Market
    ,M.Status
    ,M.Status_Sub_Type
    ,M.Update_Timestamp
    ,M.LoadDate
    ,'Parcel Match' as Match_Type
from `mother-stg-254212.DATATREE_MLS.MLS_STAGE` M  
JOIN `mother-216719.PROPERTY.PROPERTY_DETAIL` P on
M.Property_Address = P.PropertyAddressFull
and M.Property_Zip = P.PRopertyAddressZIP
```

but this query times out.
THe two matching fields Address and Zip are Strings.
It runs 6 hours and times out.

How can I make this work faster?
Thanks

Comment: How large are your table sizes? Do you need ALL the data from both tables, or can you limit it by a condition (e.g. date range, geography)? And do you have the opportunity to refactor the schema?

Comment: Hi.  I have about a 500K to 1.5M record coming in that is performing a lookup against a 128-135Mil recordset stored in GBQ.  So, I will need to create a FK based on address matching.  unfortunately this means yes. I need the full match. I'm trying to refactor the schema now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an [unbalanced joins](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-patterns#unbalanced_joins) scenario.

For this you could either try to [optimize your join patterns](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-compute#optimize_your_join_patterns). If the issue persists after this, I suggest opening an [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) so the BigQuery engineering team can verify this behavior.

Comment: Thanks much.  I reversed the tables on the join, and it sovled it in 90 minutes. much better.